# Como converter video na memoria com moviepy?

Tags: python

Estou convertendo videos em python e estou usando a biblioteca moviepy.
Estou usando as instruções:

```
clip = VideoFileClip('/home/developer/Pictures/aa.mov')
clip.write_videofile('/home/developer/Pictures/aa.mp4')
```

E está funcionando perfeitamente, porém como minha aplicação não recebe a imagem via path file estou com dificuldades em converter o arquivo. No caso estou tentando carregar o arquivo na memoria e convertelo:

```
img = open('/home/developer/Pictures/aa.mov','rb').read()
clip = VideoFileClip(img)
clip.write_videofile('/home/developer/Pictures/aa.mp4')

[1] TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Isso não dá certo pois `VideoFileClip` apenas aceita o caminho da imagem, existe alguma forma de converter o video carregando o video na memoria?

Comment: Não ficou claro porque precisa carregar o vídeo na memória. Para utilizar `open` você precisa do caminho do vídeo, então por quê não passar direto para `VideoFileClip`?

Comment: Porque eu recebo o arquivo inteiro por paramentro, eu não recebo ele via stream.